# Make chocolate with a high melting point?

Tags: chocolate

Is there something that can be done to chocolate which will raise its melting point?

I ask because [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/715/cooking-cakes-with-pop-rocks-space-dust) wanted a way of getting space dust into a cake, which might be able to be done by encasing it in chocolate chips, but to have the best chance of success the chocolate needs to have a higher melting point.  So can this be affected, and if so by what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chocolate chips made for baking have a higher melting point.

The typical tricks used by chocolate manufacturers is to change the viscosity of chocolate by adding a gel like xanthan gum or glycerine.  The other trick is to incorporate more water into the chocolate with the aid of an emulsifier such as lecithin.   All these techniques are hard to do at home as they require many hours of stirring the chocolate to avoid grittiness.  [Patents](http://www.google.com/patents?id=floKAAAAEBAJ&zoom=4&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q&f=false) often give recipes.

One can buy chocolate with higher melting points.  [Callebaut Volcano](http://www.barry-callebaut.com/84?release=5256) melts at 55°C,  the highest melting point for a commercial chocolate that I know of, but is not yet on sale.  Many of the commercial chocolate bars, such as the wartime [Hershey's Tropical Bar](http://www.hersheyarchives.org/essay/details.aspx?EssayId=39) use chocolate that incorporate these techniques as do the [Nestle Toll House morsels](http://www.verybestbaking.com/products/toll-house/morsels.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a patent from the 1940s to make chcolate with a melting point up to ~65C](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/2244569.pdf).

That's not very practical and a bit tongue-in-cheek. More practical:

- [Food-info.net's information on chocolate melting point](http://www.food-info.net/uk/qa/qa-fp45.htm).
- [Temper the chocolate](http://candy.about.com/od/candybasics/ht/temperchoc.htm).