# Why do my homemade chocolate bars start to melt as soon as I take them out of the fridge?

Tags: chocolate

I used this recipe (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GOIN-7zay6g) w/out corn syrup and honey comb bars to make a chocolate bar. The problem is that as soon as I take out a bar from fridge to eat the bar starts to melt within minute. This was my first attempt to make some thing out of chocolate bars. Is this normal/OK? Or do I need to reduce the amount of butter I used?
I made the bars as following

- melted two Cadbury's Bournville dark chocolate bars, exactly these http://www.bournville.in/html/cocoa.html, with around 150 grams of butter
- added 200 grams of classic salted peanuts
- set in the freezer for 2-3 hours

That's it. The average temperature at place where I live is not more than 27 degrees Celsius.

Comment: What's your room temperature? Pure chocolate starts melting at around 27°C, and the butter does make them melt easier than a store-bought milk chocolate bar. But maybe you could post a short list of the ingredients you used, the video is almost 15 minutes long.

Comment: Related (and actually answers this question): [What is the purpose of tempering chocolate?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/11643) Also [Make chocolate with a high melting point?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/4750) This might be a dupe of the second one.

Comment: @Aaronut thanks for the link, I have been advised my dentist to go slow on chocolates :( otherwise was planning to make another bar. You can mention your comment as an answer so that I chose it and close the question or you can use your super user powers to close it. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you don't have chocolate bars, but chocolate mixed with butter, which has a lower melting point (just like buttercream cake icing).

If it's your dentist who is advising you to go slow on chocolate, you might like to try switching away from high sugar 'candy bar' chocolate and onto higher quality chocolate with a cocoa content of 70% and over. The high-quality Swiss brand Lindt, for example, lists the sugar content of their milk chocolate as 23g per serving, but their 70% dark chocolate as 12g per serving and in their 85% super-dark as only 5g of sugar per serving.