# Are chocolate brands taking countries temperatures into account?

Tags: food-science, chocolate, melting-chocolate

Today is an unsually hot day where I live in France, we are reaching 40°C in some cities.

As I grabbed a KitKat out of its bag, I noticed that it was completly melted. It's 35°C in my appartment.
It made me wonder: *Does hot countries like Mexico, Spain or Algeria have chocolated products specifically designed to be more heat resistant ?*

And how would you achieve something like that ?

Comment: As for "How would you achieve something like that?" this may help: [Make chocolate with a high melting point](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4750/make-chocolate-with-a-high-melting-point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple: people in hot countries eat dark chocolate.  In Southern Italy, chocolate is dark as coal and almost as hard.  Mexican chocolate classically contains only cocoa, sugar, and spices.

Well-tempered dark chocolate, without dairy products, wax, or other additives with low melting points, melts at a higher temperature than your Kit-Kat does.

Per [Gizmodo](https://gizmodo.com/why-dark-chocolate-melts-in-your-mouth-not-in-your-han-1757708302)

> Dark chocolate has a higher percentage of cocoa in proportion to milk fat, so it has a higher melting point. Dark chocolate melts in your mouth; milk chocolate is much more likely to melt in your hand.